# Trying to make HTML table from MySQL database; PHP doing nothing

Tags: php

I have checked that my server's PHP is running. When I make a .php file that is just `<? php echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; ?>` it works fine.

However, when I use my code to construct this table. I get no HTML on my page source. What's going on?

```
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
    if (!$db) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM persons"); // selecting data through mysql_query()

    echo '<table border=1px>';  // opening table tag
    echo'<th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Sametime</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Ranking</th>'; //table headers

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    // we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
    echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
    echo '<td>'.$data['firstname'].$data['lastname'].'</td><td>'.$data['email'].'</td><td>'.$data['sametime'].'</td><td>'.$data['phone'].'</td><td>'.$data['ranking'].'</td>'; // we are looping all data to be printed till last row in the table
    echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
    }

    echo '</table>';  //closing table tag
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you at least see this? "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great."

Comment: Do you have opening `<?php` tag? Do you understand that `bd` is a variable and therefore should be `$bd`?

Comment: Is the `bd` on the first line a typo? In your code, it should be `$db`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: When you say you've tried `eco`, do you mean `echo`?

Comment: Also, variables like `bd =` need to be prefixed with a `$` symbol.

Comment: Sorry, those were typos. yes I meant "echo" and I have a $ before the bd; it was just not highlighted when I copied the code.

Comment: and yes I have an opening <?php tag. again just didn't copy it.

Comment: Post the _exact_ code you are running.

Comment: Please review the code in your question, and do take your time, so it is accurate. Jay has kindly fixed the things we believe you have in your code, but the first variable is still probably wrong (either just here, or in your code as well) - see Josh's remarks.

Comment: (Looks like this has been solved, missing a MySQL extension - if so this can be closed as an unreproduceable case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MySQLi in a Procedural manner, you'll need to pass `$db` to `mysqli_query($db, $query);` as it's a required parameter.

Here's a slimmed down version of your code.

```
$db = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if (!$db) {
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
}
echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!;

// PASS THE CONNECTION HERE
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM persons");
```

Comment: You should be getting the *actual* errors from the database connection.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Agreed, removed it just to keep the code simple for the example. Added them back.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed you have `$bd` above as your connection, change it to `$db`.

Comment: yeah I mentioned in an above comment that was a typo. the $ is there on the file.

Comment: I'm just getting a blank page when I load the webpage now. I'm not sure

Comment: It's not the $ that's wrong, the letters are backwards BD vs. DB, I'd suggest $db if it's a database. ;)

Comment: I have no idea how that's a BD on here as it is $db on my file. But yeah that's all good on my file. Any idea why I'm still getting a blank page then?

Comment: Enable errors. Add this to the top of your file just under the opening `<?php` tag. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Ok, update the question with all of the code you have now.

Comment: found it... Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/index.php on line 16\n'

Comment: Well, sounds like the MySQLi extension isn't installed. What's the line of code on line 16?

Comment: I am using a new php server client for this project and assumed it came with mysqli or mysql installed >_<